# PHP Normalise percentage values across range

Tags: php, math, numbers, normalization

I have an array of numbers and the ammount of properties in the array cannot be determined.

```
example:

array(30, 30, 10, 20, 60);
array(2, 53, 71, 22);
array(88, 22, 8);
etc...
```

Now normally, the sum of all the array values will be 100 or less.

What I want to do is, when they are over 100, reduce them all to make it equal to 100. Normally i would just divide the difference and then take away but for example, the first array adds up to 150, and if I divide the difference (50) evenly, i would end up with:

```
array(20, 20, 0, 10, 50);
```

But i want the numbers to be subtracted according to their size, so 30 would have a larger chunk taken out then 10.

The way I would do it is divide each value by (total_sum / 100), and that works perfectly. Now what I need to do is be able to select one value which becomes dominant and cannot be subtracted from then subtract all other values until sum is 100. Example below:

```
array(20, 20, 80); // 80 is the dominant number

After normalising, the array would be:

array(10, 10, 80);

Example 2:

array(20, 20, 40, 60); // 40 is dominant number

after normalising:

array(10, 10, 40, 20) // maybe it wouldnt be those exact values bhut just to show how different size numbers get reduced according to size. But now total sum is 100

Example 3:
array(23, 43, 100, 32) // 100 is dominant
normalise
array(0, 0, 100, 0);
```

I have tried so many things but nothing seems to work. How would i accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like more of a logic problem than a PHP question. Can you elaborate on "I want the numbers to be subtracted according to their size"? In your examples, you just don't modify your largest number. Are you looking for log scaling? What if your largest number is more than 100?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're just about done. Just remove the dominant value from your input array, reduce the `100` by that value, and do the rest like before:

```
function helper($values, $sum) {
  $f = array_sum($values) / $sum;
  return array_map(function ($v) use($f) {
    return $v / $f;
  }, $values);
}

// input
$a = array(20, 20, 40, 60);

// remove the dominant value (index: 2)
$b = array_splice($a, 2, 1);

// `normalize` the remaining values using `100 - dominant value` instead of `100`
$c = helper($a, 100 - $b[0]);

// re-inject the dominant value
array_splice($c, 2, 0, $b);

// output
print_r($c); // => [12, 12, 40, 36]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
function normalise_array($array_to_work_on,$upper_limit){

    $current_total = array_sum($array_to_work_on);
    $reduce_total_by = $current_total - $upper_limit;
    $percentage_to_reduce_by = floor(($reduce_total_by / $current_total) * 100);

    $i = 0;
    $new_array;
    foreach($array_to_work_on as $item){
        $reduce = ($item / 100) * $percentage_to_reduce_by;
        $new_array[$i] = floor($item - $reduce);
        $i ++;
        echo $new_array[$i];
    }
    return($new_array);
}

$numbers1 = array(30, 30, 10, 20, 89);
print_r(normalise_array($numbers1,20));
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />First array total: ".array_sum(normalise_array($numbers1,20));

echo "<br /><br/ >";

$numbers2 = array(234, 30, 10, 20, 60);
print_r(normalise_array($numbers2,100));

echo "<br />First array total: ".array_sum(normalise_array($numbers2,100));
```

Comment: Actually - after some testing I have found that it doesn't work all that well with large numbers. I will look into it later today. Maybe it will be a starting point for you?